# if vs else if method comparing

Tags: c#, if-statement

I wonder if there is any difference between those methods

```
public bool GetCondition(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.StartsWith('a'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (s2.StartsWith('c'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    if (s1.StartsWith('b') && s2.StartsWith('d'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

and

```
public bool GetCondition(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.StartsWith('a'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (s2.StartsWith('c'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    else if (s1.StartsWith('b') && s2.StartsWith('d'))
    {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Are they equal or is there a different behaviour to expect? If not, what is the better way to write?

Comment: Its the same. One could say that in the second option, `else` is redundant, but its up to personal taste more than anything else.

Comment: Because you `return` if the `if` statement is true, it should be the same.  Otherwise the first would be slower because all three `if`'s would be processed.

Comment: @JayBuckman "*Otherwise the first would be slower...*", not only slower, semantically *very* different.

Comment: Thanks @inbetween, I should have pointed that out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your case no, there is no difference but normally there is one

if you use

```
if(...){
}
if(...){
}
if(...){
}
```

it will go through every if even if one of them is correct,

but if you use :

```
if(...){
}
else if(...){
}
else if(...){
}
```

and if is true is will ignore the else if's completly

Answer (score 0):

In this case they are equal because you exit when condition is true.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, there are equal.

You can write it like this:

```
public bool GetCondition(string s1, string s2)
{
    if (s1.StartsWith('a') || s2.StartsWith('c') || (s1.StartsWith('b') && s2.StartsWith('d')))
    {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

But, the two examples that you presented are good too. Choose the one that seams better for you to understand.

Comment: In the particular code he's asking about, both options are, for all purposes, exactly the same.

Comment: Because of the return in each if, then subsequent if statements will NOT be evaluated in the first example.

Comment: Yes, they are equal :)